# JavaScript drag and drop game new level

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

Hello stack overflow team!

I am a beginner at web development and I ran into few problems while working on my simple JS drag and drop game. I will try to explain as clear as I can the problems I am facing on this little project.

1. I can't figure how to make a 2nd level for the game. So once a player submits his answers, the next level appears (same style, just different body parts). I was looking for answers on google, but it seems I just don't know how to find it or it is not there.
2. Another problem I would like to fix is when you dragging a picture to a drop zone, I would like that picture to appear on the drop zone instead of a blank space.
3. The last problem I would like to fix is when you dragging target to a dropping area you cannot drop it anywhere else except on the "right" area. How to change that, so you could drop the target onto any dropping area?
4. The last problem is how to keep all the elements in the middle? I was playing around with css a lot, but I just couldn't get it done. I tried to change positions, used these properties:

   left: 50%;
   margin-right: -50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   But it doesn't work...

Here is the html, css and js code:

```js
//CREATING VARIABLE TO INCREASE THE SCORE
var i = 0;
i++;

//SETTING UP THE ONDRAGSTART EVENT DATA/IMAGES THAT I WANT TO MOVE
function dragStart1(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text1", event.target.id);
}

function dragStart2(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text2", event.target.id);
}

function dragStart3(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text3", event.target.id);
}

//PREVENTING DEFAULT BROWSER SETTINGS SO IT WOULDNT ACT WEIRD
function dragOver1(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function dragOver2(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function dragOver3(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

//GETTING THE DATA/IMAGES I NEED WHEN IT IS BEING DROPPED ON THE DROP AREAS
function onDrop4(event) {
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text1");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  dropArea1.innerHTML = "<img src=\"Img/heart.png\>";
  score.innerHTML = i++;
  //changing the style back to normal after dragging is done
  dropArea1.style.background = "";
  dropArea1.style.border = "";
}

function onDrop5(event) {
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text2");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  dropArea2.innerHTML = "<img src=\"Img/lungs.png\>";
  score.innerHTML = i++;
  //changing the style back to normal after dragging is done
  dropArea2.style.background = "";
  dropArea2.style.border = "";
}

function onDrop6(event) {
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text3");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  dropArea3.innerHTML = "<img src=\"Img/stomach.png\>";
  score.innerHTML = i++;
  //changing the style back to normal after dragging is done
  dropArea3.style.background = "";
  dropArea3.style.border = "";
}

//PREVENTING DEFAULT BROWSER SETTINGS FROM ACTING WEIRD
function onDrop1(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function onDrop2(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function onDrop3(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

//SETTING UP A FUNCTION FOR "SUBMIT" BUTTON TO ALERT CONGRATS MESSAGE
function submitAnsw() {
  if (i > 3) {
    alert("Congratulations! You know the main human organs!");
  } else {
    alert("You are very close! Don't give up!");
  }
}

//CHANGING THE STYLE OF THE DROP AREAS ONCE THE IMAGE IS BEING DRAGGED ON THEM
function dragEnter1(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  dropArea1.style.background = "lightblue";
  dropArea1.style.border = "3px solid black";
}

function dragEnter2(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  dropArea2.style.background = "lightblue";
  dropArea2.style.border = "3px solid black";
}

function dragEnter3(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  dropArea3.style.background = "lightblue";
  dropArea3.style.border = "3px solid black";
}

//CHANGING THE STYLE OF DROPAREAS ONCE THE DRAGGABLE IMAGE LEAVES THE DROP AREA
function dragLeave1(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  dropArea1.style.background = "lightskyblue";
  dropArea1.style.border = "3px solid #666666";
}

function dragLeave2(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  dropArea2.style.background = "lightskyblue";
  dropArea2.style.border = "3px solid #666666";
}

function dragLeave3(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  dropArea3.style.background = "lightskyblue";
  dropArea3.style.border = "3px solid #666666";
}
```

```css
/* STYLE BY AURIMAS RANSYS */

.dropArea {
  float: left;
  width: 210px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #666666;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 15%;
}

.dragImg {
  float: left;
  width: 210px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  top: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 210px;
  height: 150px;
  cursor: move;
}

header {
  color: navy;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1 {
  color: navy;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

p {
  color: navy;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2em;
}


/*
Code is available at https://www.bestcssbuttongenerator.com/#/38
 */

.myButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #caefab;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #caefab;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #caefab;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #77d42a), color-stop(1, #5cb811));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #77d42a 5%, #5cb811 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #77d42a 5%, #5cb811 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #77d42a 5%, #5cb811 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #77d42a 5%, #5cb811 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #77d42a 5%, #5cb811 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#77d42a', endColorstr='#5cb811', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #77d42a;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #268a16;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #306108;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 6px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #aade7c;
}

.myButton:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #5cb811), color-stop(1, #77d42a));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5cb811 5%, #77d42a 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5cb811 5%, #77d42a 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5cb811 5%, #77d42a 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5cb811 5%, #77d42a 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5cb811 5%, #77d42a 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5cb811', endColorstr='#77d42a', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #5cb811;
}

.myButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Anatomy Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- HEADER -->
  <header>Human Anatomy Game</header>
  <h1>Level 1</h1> <br><br><br><br><br><br>

  <!-- ADDING THE SCORE -->
  <p>Score: <text id="score">0</text> </p>


  <!-- IMAGES FOR DROPPING -->
  <div class="dragImg" ondrop="onDrop1(event)">
    <img src="Img/heart.png" ondragstart="dragStart1(event)" draggable="true" id="img1">
  </div>

  <div class="dragImg" ondrop="onDrop2(event)">
    <img src="Img/lungs.png" ondragstart="dragStart2(event)" draggable="true" id="img2">
  </div>

  <div class="dragImg" ondrop="onDrop3(event)">
    <img src="Img/stomach.png" ondragstart="dragStart3(event)" draggable="true" id="img3">
  </div>

  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />


  <!-- IMAGES DROPZONE -->
  <div id="dropArea1" class="dropArea" ondrop="onDrop4(event)" ondragover="dragOver1(event)" ondragenter="dragEnter1(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave1(event)">HEART</div>
  <div id="dropArea2" class="dropArea" ondrop="onDrop5(event)" ondragover="dragOver2(event)" ondragenter="dragEnter2(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave2(event)">LUNGS</div>
  <div id="dropArea3" class="dropArea" ondrop="onDrop6(event)" ondragover="dragOver3(event)" ondragenter="dragEnter3(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave3(event)">STOMACH</div>

  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />


  <!-- BUTTON TO SUBMIT YOUR SELECTIONS -->
  <button class="myButton" onclick="submitAnsw()">Submit</button>

</body>

</html>
```

I would really appreciate a good feedback and answers to my problems as it is my first work and I want to improve greatly. Also I would like to incorporate JS libraries on this project, so any advice how will do!

P.S. I am sorry for my english, it is not my first language, but I tried to be as clear as possible.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Whilst you put in a lot of effort into your post, you have to understand the concept behind SO questions. Questions that ask for oppinions and advice are not meant to be here, questions that are in themselves a problem to be solved, like an error or an explenation as to WHY something behaves the way it does is what is the purpose of this forum, dare I call it that.  your question on "how do i make next level appear" is not a question on why something isnt working or works like this, its a "solve it for me" and we do not do that.

Comment: Second question I do not even understand, the third one is again "how to code this feature", and lastly the fourth one is probably the only one that could qualify as a question to ask here, however it is pretty vague on what you want to do. If you were to post only THAT as a separate question im sure it would be received better. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I also want to touch on one last thing: "I would also like to incorporate JS libraries on this project". Why? Do you NEED them? If no then do not use them. Having libraries just for the sake of having them is a really bad way to start coding. Once you run into issues that libraries solve for you (and im certain there are some libraries that could help you with your task here) then you ask yourself do you want to use them and most of them come with instructions on how to implement them. It is still not the best way to learn though.

Comment: @Dellirium Thank you for your feedback! Even though I understood what about this forum is, I have to admit I am a little bit confused now, since I am not sure how to move on with this little project now... I just want to learn how to make more levels on this simple game, keep all the elements in the middle of the website and when you dragging elements (targets) to the drop zones once you drop them to appear where you drop them. I understand that no one probably will bother to help on these matters, but I was hoping maybe you could point me to where I should look for help?

Comment: You can separate your task into multiple subtasks, isolate them, make minimum examples of each, solve them one by one. Google is your friend when trying to learn how to do any of these, there is plenty of people posting small questions, but none posting multiple questions at once that give exact solutions. So first, try to make your drag and drop. Once you run into issues, post only THAT as a question and show what you tried already, show any errors in console, etc. Then people will help you. Repeat for each of the issues one at a time, that is the best you can do.

Comment: take a loot at this post's revision, the person asked a question, showed no code, no examples, was very vague, then over the course of 5-6 edits he eventually managed to give a good "issue" example, and it is only at that point that I was able to help him. It turns out that it was a single line of code that was wrong, but there is no way anyone can see or predict that when he unloaded his entire page into the example. Eventually he did what was asked of him and got help, so you should do the same. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51152265/revisions